# How to use angularJS page preloader?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use an preloader for my AngularJS app, I want something like, when user opens my website first time, a loader shows and it should be gone when all callback functions are done with their work.

Here is what i tried:

```
 var App = angular.module('App.directives', []);
 App.directive('routeLoadingIndicator', function($rootScope){
   return {
   restrict:'E',
   template:"<h1 ng-if='isRouteLoading' style='position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; z-index: 2147483647;' >Loading...</h1>",
   link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
     scope.isRouteLoading = false;

     $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
       scope.isRouteLoading = true;
     });

     $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(){
       scope.isRouteLoading = false;
     });
   }
 };
});
```

$routeChangeSuccess only work when the template is completely loaded, but i need a solution that trigger when all callbacks completes e.g. $http requests. I want to add an loader that appear when user clicks on a link, and loader will get invisible when the page is loaded completely including all $http requests

Comment: does this work? are you getting any errors? what is the actual question?

Comment: start with ng-init. Its first thing in the angular life cycle

Comment: $routeChangeSuccess only work when the template is completely loaded, but i need a solution that trigger when all callbacks completes e.g. $http requests. I want to add an loader that appear when user clicks on a link, and loader will get invisible when the page is loaded completely including all $http requests

Comment: perhaps you should add that detail to the question body.

Comment: oh yes, thanks
I am new to stackoverflow